# Кодировка mysql. Не добавляются русские символы в БД

Tags: кодировка, php, mysql

Установил xampp перестали добавлятся русские символы через форму в БД. До этого стоял денвер, все работало нормально. Подскажите как исправить проблему. Везде используется cp-1251.

Answer (score 1):

чтобы не было проблем с кодировкой, у вас везде должна быть одна и та же кодировка

1. В БД (и база и таблицы)
2. В файле (кодировка html или php файла)
3. В метатеге meta charset
4. В браузере (в настройках)
5. И по возможности в htaccess - AddDefaultCharset utf8 (если это utf8)

Если все это не помогло, возможно, как вы и говорили, в my.ini по дефолту стоит левая кодировка

Answer (score 0):

Используйте UTF-8
В БД установите кодировку utf8_general_ci

Comment: а почему в денвере все работало нормально. Может проблема в настройках my.ini?